# Parameters for Exponential function with maximum likelihood in R

Tags: r, exponential

I got a sample data and i'm trying to obtain the parameters for two-parameter exponential function calculed based on maximum likelihood.

My sample:

```
sample = c(136.5,150,94.1,127.6,77.2,136.1,83.4,75.6,92.7,106.5,95.9,112.1,80.7,90.4,143.7,152.7,113.3,143.9,87.9,85.2,117.2,193,153.7,84.7,97.3,140.3,80,103.6,72.6,90.7,52.6,52.8)
```

My main goal is to use the `cdf` or `quantile` of exponential for maximum likelihood, just like that:

Example with GEV:

```
library(nsRFA)

parameters <- ML_estimation(sample, dist = "GEV")
p = c(0.1,0.066667,0.05,0.04,0.033333,0.02,0.01,0.005,0.002,0.001,0.0002,0.0001)
q = invF.GEV(1-p, parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3]); q
> 149.4 158.8 165.2 170 173.9 184.3 197.6 210 225.4 236.2 258.9 267.7
```

Comment: The documentation seems to be referencing the `.sample_generator` function: `.sample_generator(10, c(0, 1), dist = "EXP")`. Edit: This unfortunately doesn't solve your original question, though!

Comment: you,re right! i cant use this library

Comment: Do you want `MASS::fitdistr(x, "exponential")`? Package `MASS` is a base package, no need to install it.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, the problem is: this dont give parameters by maximum likelihood

Comment: Yes it does. Read `help("fitdistr")` first sentence (title): **Maximum-likelihood Fitting of Univariate Distributions**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **two-parameter** exponential function is an exponential function with a lower endpoint at `xi`. Finding MLEs of distributions with such sharp boundary points is a bit of a special case: the MLE for the boundary *is equal to the minimum value observed in the data set* (see e.g. [this CrossValidated question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/131230/maximum-likelihood-estimate-for-uniform-distribution)).  That makes the MLE of the two-parameter exponential equivalent to the MLE of the exponential distribution for `x-xmin`.

So the MLE of `xi` is

```
print(xi <- min(sample))
```

1. With `MASS::fitdistr`:

```r
(m0 <- MASS::fitdistr(sample-xi, "exponential"))
      rate    
  0.018382353 
 (0.003249572)
```

2. with `bbmle`:

```r
m1 <- bbmle::mle2(y-xi~dexp(lambda), 
      data=data.frame(y=sample), start=list(lambda=1),
      method="Brent", lower=0.001, upper=100)
broom::tidy(m1, conf.int=TRUE, conf.method="profile")
```

```
  term   estimate std.error statistic      p.value conf.low conf.high
  <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl>
1 lambda   0.0184   0.00325      5.66 0.0000000154   0.0127    0.0255
```

3. Analytical solution:

```r
1/mean(sample-xi)
## [1] 0.01838235
```

If you want a simple function that provides the shift and scale parameters (as apparently provided by your alternative software):

```r
est_twoexp <- function(x) {
   xi <- min(x)
   c(xi = xi, scale = mean(sample-xi))
}
est_twoexp(sample)
##    xi scale 
##  52.6  54.4
```

```r
est_twoexp <- function(x) {
   xi <- min(x)
   c(xi = xi, scale = mean(sample-xi))
}
est_twoexp(sample)
##    xi scale 
##  52.6  54.4
```

Plotting:

```r
library(nsRFA)
ee <- ecdf(sample)
inv_ecdf <- approxfun(seq(0, 1, length=length(sample)),
                      sort(sample),
                      method="constant")
## homemade quantile function
q2exp <- function(p, xi, scale) {
  xi + qexp(p, rate=1/scale)
}
```

```r
curve(inv_ecdf(x), from=0, to=1, type="s", ylim=c(40,250))
with(as.list(est_twoexp(sample)),
     curve( invF.exp (x, xi, scale), col=2, lwd=2, add=TRUE))
with(as.list(est_twoexp(sample)),
     curve( q2exp(x, xi, scale), col=4, lwd=2, lty= 2, add=TRUE))
```

`glm` with `family=Gamma` doesn't work because it doesn't allow zero values (within the general family of Gamma distributions, `x==0` only has a positive, finite density for the exponential distribution)

Comment: Hi Ben, thanks for the answer. But i cant get the correct values for quantile function of exponential with this parameters. Try these with invF.exp(1-p, param1, param2)...

Comment: I will check, but: is it really the case that `qexp(p, 0.009345794)` is incorrect ... ?

Comment: OK, it looks like you are asking about a **two-parameter exponential distribution**, which is not the most common usage of "exponential distribution" ...

Comment: Sorry for the mess, i just edited the post

Comment: Hey Ben. Great work. I think i willn't got a better answer. The results of qexp(1-p, 0.01838235) are in the expected order of magnitude, but not quite the results I was expecting. I use software (alea ehr) that gives me both parameters: alpha and beta (56.15 and 50.85). But looks like that doesn't exist any function for this in R.

Comment: I'm assuming that alpha and beta are shift and scale parameters.  I don't know why the results are different.  Is there a link for the software you're using (I can't find it with a web search), especially a link that's informative about its procedures for this estimation procedure?

Comment: There is an english version http://www.ehr.ufmg.br/downloads/
its from my university, but i think its not well documented. The input is a .txt with the sample, distributed in only one column.

Comment: OK. Are you sure the estimated parameters you're quoting are MLEs and not (e.g.) from method of moments or L-moments?

Comment: Yes, because i can see all at the same time

Comment: I'm probably going to have to give up there (I'm not going to download the software and play around with it [Windows version only, no source code, etc. etc.]). There certainly could be something wrong with my approach, but I can't see what it would be.

Comment: nsRFA package can do it, but for others distributions. but i appreciate all the effort.